# Cómo inicializar arreglo de objetos en JAVA?

Tags: java, poo, objeto

Hola queridos programadores. 
El asunto es que soy nuevo con el lenguaje Java y tengo un problema al inicializar con valores un arreglo de objetos. El código es el siguiente:

```
public static void limpiarRegistroAlumno(int indice){
    int i = indice;
    alumnos[i].codigo = 0;
    alumnos[i].nombre = "";
    alumnos[i].carrera = "";
    alumnos[i].promedio = 0;
    registrosAlumnosSinDatos[i] = true;
}
```

Mi clase es la siguiente. A la cual le declaro los atributos de esta forma para simular el struct de C:

```
class Alumno{
    int codigo;
    String nombre;
    String carrera;
    float promedio;
}
```

Al correrlo me tira este error al cual no he encontrado solución:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ejercicio54.Ejercicio54.limpiarRegistroAlumno(Ejercicio54.java:23)
at ejercicio54.Ejercicio54.inicializarPrograma(Ejercicio54.java:33)
at ejercicio54.Ejercicio54.main(Ejercicio54.java:188)
C:\Users\Condoplaza 1\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-
snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Tengo más líneas de código pero el error principal es al tratar de inicializar el arreglo de objetos.
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema (sin ver todo el código) es que intentas dar valores a los alumnos pero no los has creado, con lo cual al intentar darle valor a alguno de sus atributos da la excepción.

Tienes 2 arrays, registrosAlumnosSinDatos que parece ser un array de bool, con ese no tendrás problema porque al crearlo te pondrá todos a false, pero el array de alumnos es otra cosa.

El array de alumnos lo tienes que inicializar, para esto, tienes que crear un alumno por cada posición del array.

```
for(int i=0; i<numAlumnos; i++)
{
    alumnos[i] = new Alumno();
}
```

Con esto debería solucionar tu problema

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AppAlumno {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     int numAlumnos = 10;
      Alumno arrayAlumnos[] = new Alumno[numAlumnos];
      for (int i = 0; i < numAlumnos; i++) {
         Alumno alumno = new Alumno();
         arrayAlumnos[i] = alumno;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < arrayAlumnos.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arrayAlumnos[i]);
      }
    } 
}

public class Alumno {
private int codigo;
private String nombre;
private String carrera;
private float promedio;
//se inicializan en el constructor 
public Alumno() {
    this.codigo = 0;
    this.nombre = "";
    this.carrera = "";
    this.promedio = 0;
}

public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getCarrera() {
    return carrera;
}

public void setCarrera(String carrera) {
    this.carrera = carrera;
}

public float getPromedio() {
    return promedio;
}

public void setPromedio(float promedio) {
    this.promedio = promedio;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Alumno{" + "codigo=" + codigo + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", carrera=" + carrera + ", promedio=" + promedio + '}';
}
}
```

Te dejo un ejemplo de como deberías inicializar tus objetos. 
De igual forma me gustaría saber si tus arreglos **registrosAlumnosSinDatos** y **alumnos** los declaraste como variables globales y si es así están inicializadas? lo cual podría causar el problema del **NullPointerException** al momento que tratas de settear algún valor.

Te recomiendo leer un poco mas acerca de encapsulacion para que no modifiques tu variables directamente.

Saludos :)